# Loading a page into wordpress

Tags: wordpress, load

Alright, Im in the process of creating a custom wordpress theme.

My index page is getting super crowded with code so im wondering..

If i were to create an additional page.. say, "topplayers.php"

would I be able to load that into the position where I want it to appear on my index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into [php includes](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php%20includes). I'm not too familiar with wordpress themes when it comes to their creation but something like:

```
<?php include('path/to/file.php'); ?>
```

Should provide the functionality your after.

If it is integral to the site - i.e if its not there the site shouldn't load, you can use `require` instead of `include`.

Comment: Awesome man, Worked flawlessy. Really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you're happy with the answer be sure to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can make an include.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

One cool way of doing it (if you place the file in your wordpress directory) is this way:

```
<?php include(get_template_directory() . 'topplayers.php'); ?>
```